# Append string to textinput on button release using kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a method for selecting a file using `kivy filechooser` and I want to load the content of the file I read into `TextInput` field after I hit `Load` button.

I am not sure if I use variable `text_from_file` in `.kv` file correctly, but I am stuck at this point and not sure what else to do here.

What I tried is I have stored the string from file into `self.text_from_file` and then assigned it to the `self.usecase` variable, where in `.kv` file, I have used `usecase` to map the `textinput` field. But the string does not appear in the `textinput` field after I hit `Load` button.

This is my python code `(main.py)`:

```
class Grid(Widget):
load = ObjectProperty(None)
cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
text_from_file = ObjectProperty(None)
usecase = ObjectProperty(None)

def show_load_list(self):
    content = LoadDialog(load=self.load_list, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
    self._popup = Popup(title="Load a file list", content=content, size_hint=(1, 1))
    self._popup.open()

def load_list(self, path, filename):
    with open(filename[0], 'r') as file:
        self.text_from_file = file.read()
    self.usecase = self.text_from_file
    self.dismiss_popup()

def dismiss_popup(self):
    self._popup.dismiss()
```

This is `main.kv`:

```
<Grid>
    usecase: use_case_text

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            TextInput:
                id: use_case_text
                multiline: True

        Button:
            text: "Import use case"
            on_press: root.show_load_list()


<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            path: './'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()
            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that I was missing `.text` part for `ObjectProperty()`:

`self.text_from_file.text = string`